# Was there a Baggins at Bag End after Frodo left for the Undying Lands?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the beginning of the first LOTR movie, Bilbo narrates

> "*....There has always been a Baggins at Bag End and there always will
> be.*"

But after Frodo leaves for the Undying Lands, who was the Baggins at Bag End? I know that Samwise inherited Bag End, but he is not a Baggins.  So, when Bilbo was narrating about a Baggins always being in the Bag End, was it his wishful thinking? Perhaps, in-doubt, as a question i.e. "Will there always be a Baggins at Bag End?". You know, because things are made to endure in the Shire and what not.

Comment: [Who Inherited Bag End?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37949/who-inherited-bag-end?rq=1)

Comment: Bilbo has no foresight, so there's no reason to take the statement (which I think is film only) literally. It is most likely that he was referring to his plan to leave the Shire and install Frodo as his heir, thus ensuring that Bag End would remain in the family for another generation (or so he thought).

Comment: @IanThompson Of course, given that the framing story of the Lord of the Rings is that it is Bilbo and Frodo's memoirs, anything the narrator says should in theory have perfect foresight of the end of the story.

Comment: @Showsni It isn't the narrator, it's Bilbo, saying something at a particular time. Even if I'm telling the story of my past, I might record the exact thing I said at that time, even if it turned out to be wrong.

Comment: There are many instances of in the books that don't assume omniscience on the part of the author. It makes more sense to assume that the English translations use the Red Book et al. as source material rather than literal translations.